# How to get checkbox values to save into a text file?

Tags: python, tkinter, output

Here is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def var_states():
   print("Option 1: %d\nOption 2: %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get()))

Label(master, text="Option").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Option 1", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Option 2", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=var_states).grid(row=4, sticky=W, pady=4)




mainloop()
```

This brings up the following screen:

[image]

If one checkbox is selected and clicked show the output for CMD is this:

[image]

Next, I am trying to save the output into a .txt file. This is what I have tried:

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(var_states())
f.close()

#open and read the file after the appending:
f = open("output.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

But this returns me the following error: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None`

But if I convert this `f.write(var_states())` to `f.write(str(var_states()))`

It does the job, but prints out `None` into the .txt file.

How do i get the checkbox values to save into a .txt file as the CMD outputs it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var_states` function doesn't actually return anything. It just prints to the console. Change it to:

```py
def var_states():
   res = "Option 1: %d\nOption 2: %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get())
   print(res)
   return res
```

---

Also, instead of manually `open`ing and `close`ing files, you should use `with`:

```py
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write(var_states())

#open and read the file after the appending:
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
  print(f.read())
```

The file is automatically `close`d at the end of the `with` block.